# Matplotlib - Label values as inputs from user

Tags: python, matplotlib, input

How I can get input from user with matplotlib library? 
I would like to add data from input into the labels.

I have tried adding title in this way:

```
plt.xlabel(input("enter title:"))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Some details: I work on Android using Pydroid 3. Error message: EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: `plt.xlabel(raw_input("enter title:"))` Does this work?

Comment: I got an other error: NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Does EOF error occur for all input strings or some specific strings?

Comment: EOF error occur for all input strings.